# MySQL select all left entries from a table which is joined from another table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following MySQL-Statement:

```
SELECT      norm.NormID, norm.NormName
FROM        (assignment
INNER JOIN  norm
ON          assignment.NID = norm.NormID )
INNER JOIN  wire
ON          assignment.LID = wire.WireID
WHERE       wire.WireID= 109 
ORDER BY    norm.NormName;
```

Now what I got are the entries from the table assignment with the NormID and NormName for that WireID. 
What I want to get are the entries from the table norm, which are not setted for this WireID.

E.g.: 
WireID has the norm assignment A, B, D, G.

The table norm has the entries A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H.

What I want to get from the MySQL-Statment are the entries C, E, F, H.

How can I select those left norm entries for this WireID?

With the above statement I would get:

---

```
-----------------------
| NormID  | NormName  |
-----------------------
| 1       |  A        |
| 2       |  B        |
| 4       |  D        |
| 7       |  G        |
-----------------------
```

I want to have this Table:

```
-----------------------
| NormID  | NormName  |
-----------------------
| 3       |  C        |
| 5       |  E        |
| 6       |  F        |
| 8       |  H        |
-----------------------
```

Comment: much better to show some clear data here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (if I understood what you asked) you can try this :

```
SELECT      norm.NormID, norm.NormName
FROM        assignment
INNER JOIN  norm ON assignment.NID = norm.NormID
LEFT JOIN   wire ON assignment.LID = wire.WireID
WHERE       assignment.LID= 109 
        AND wire.wireID IS NULL
ORDER BY    norm.NormName;
```

**Edit after your comments.**
I think you could use:

```
SELECT      A.NormID, A.NormName
FROM        norm A
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT NID FROM assignment WHERE LID = 109) B ON B.NID = A.NormID
WHERE       B.NID IS NULL     
ORDER BY    A.NormName;
```

OR

```
SELECT      A.NormID, A.NormName
FROM        norm A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM assignment WHERE LID = 109 AND ASSIGNMENT.NID = A.NormID)
ORDER BY    A.NormName;
```

Comment: nope. If I execute the statement without the AND wire.wireID IS NULL, I would get all the entries of NormName and NormID from the assignment table for that WireID. I want to get the entries from the norm table, which are not setted for that WireID in the assignment table

Comment: Can you post some sample data, please (as INSERT script if possible and CREATE TABLE) and output desired

Comment: @Alex I posted revised queries

Comment: Thank you... That is what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

after you added a sample data the entries that are not setted with 109 wireid are these:

```
SELECT      norm.NormID, norm.NormName
FROM        assignment
inner JOIN  norm
ON          assignment.NID = norm.NormID 
INNER JOIN  wire
ON          assignment.LID = wire.WireID
WHERE       wire.WireID <> 109 
ORDER BY    norm.NormName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  norm.NormID,norm.NormName from norm
Inner JOIN
assignment on assignment.NID = norm.NormID
where assignment.LID in(select wireID from Wire where WireID = 109)
```

Im not so sure coz i dont have your data